# How to subscribe a hosted (background) service to a Hub as a client?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, asp.net-core-hosted-services

**The Problem:**
How to establish a hosted service (background service) which can **receive**, process and send messages from a signalR hub?

**The story:**
*Step 1.* Client #1 runs a blazor (server-side) App. The App creates a `Hub`, subscribes a client to the `Hub` and starts a `HostedService` which is also subscribed to this `Hub`. 
*Step 2.* Client #2 runs another instance of the App. This instance finds an existing `Hub` and subscribes the client #2 to it. (Neither the hosted service nor the new Hub is created by this instance as it is already started in step 1)
*Step 3.* The `HostedService` (created in step 1) loads certain data from a file (JSON) and then starts a `PeriodicTimer` which is looped. Upon every loop the data is recalculated and broadcasted to all clients every 5 seconds.
*Step 4.* Clients #1 nad #2 send messages to `HostedService` through the `Hub`. The conent of these messages has influence on the looped recalculation algorithm.

I am stuck at Step 4. I cannot think of a way how to enable `HostedService` to receive messages. 
Anyway I am open to any suggestions on this architectrue.

Comment: How do you register the HostedService?(AddScoped or AddSingelton or ...)

Comment: As a scoped service.

Comment: Please try as a singleton and also as a transient.